# Is QueryPerformanceCounter guaranteed to give you time since boot?

Tags: c, winapi, performancecounter

Is it safe to assume that the count returned from [QueryPerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) relates to the time since the last system boot? Or could it be reset while the system is running? The MSDN article itself doesn't guarantee this, however I've seen some 3rd party information (such as [this](http://www.decompile.com/cpp/faq/windows_timer_api.htm)) that says that this is the case.

Comment: You might want to define what "boot" means. If the system goes into sleep or hibernation mode, when it awakes will the counter: 1) reset to 0; 2) start where it left off before going to sleep; 3) be adjusted to include the time that it spent in sleep/hibernation? In general, I don't think you can count on `QueryPerformanceCounter` giving you "time since boot." As the response said, it's for relative times. You can't say with any reliability what the base time is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's meant to be used for relative times. But I don't think it can be used to measure time since boot.

From what I hear, it's implemented using the `rdtsc` instruction which measures "pseudo" CPU cycles since the CPU was powered on. In that case, yes, it probably does give the time since boot, but I don't think this is specified.

Comment: `It's meant to be used for relative times` ok so it may be time since boot + N. So it will be ever increasing after boot, but not guaranteed to be a measurement of the time of boot?

Comment: I don't see any "official" documentation stating that it measures the time since boot. But there's plenty of 3rd-party sites that say it does...

Comment: Even if it is meant for relative times, the only way it can meet the requirements for that usage is by increasing monotonically at a stable rate. Resets are definitely out of the question; they would result in negative relative times. Of course I have no idea if Windows guarantees any sane behavior here (versus POSIX which does guarantee sane behavior for `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`).